# I need Help in regex function in sql Query

Tags: sql

Fetch the data Excluding ARI7879 from the data in column
Eg Data in table

```
Column
ARI78794626
ARI78794627
ARI78794628
ARI78794629
ARI78794630
```

Output:

```
_col0
4626
4627
4628
4629
4630
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and regex support is highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Will ARI7879 always be the leading characters, or can they be positioned anywhere in the column? Will the leading characters always be ARI7879?

Comment: Looks like a simple `replace(the_column, 'ARI7879', '')`  I don't see a reason to use regex

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the substring function in mysql. Which will take parameters like column name, starting index and last index(optional if you want till the end).

example :

```
Select substring(column_name, startIndex, lastIndex) as AliasName from table_name.
```

In your case:

```
Select substring(column, 8) as _col0 from Data;
```

Note:

1. 7 is the length of the ARI7879 so starting from 8.
2. last index is not mentioned as you want all remaining character

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex_substring

- [^] whatever is marked with `^` will be ignored.
- `.*` will pick any character
- [^ARI7879].* will hence pick any character except the one specififed

```
    SELECT column,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '[^ARI7879].*') new_str FROM data
```

You can use this with following databases:

- SNOWFLAKE
- MySQL 8.0 and above
- Oracle
  I hope I am not missing any other db